# postgresql handle conflict on delete

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, delete

I have a table that looks roughly like this:

```
create table people (
    id bigserial primary key,
    name varchar,
    deleted timestamp with time zone,
    parent bigint references people(id)
        on delete restrict
        on update cascade
)
```

I would like to do something like

```
delete from people where name = $1
on conflict people_parent_fkey do
update set deleted = now() where name = $1
```

but I don't think that this is supported.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What kind of "conflict" are you expecting there? Surely it can't be a duplicated unique value.

Comment: I guess it isn't a conflict. I was trying to mimic an "upsert" that I have elsewhere. Is there another form of error handling that can react when the "on delete restrict" kicks in?